# deobfuscate ip addresses in python dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I need to parse a file that contains flat text and extract both valid ip addresses and obfuscated ip addresses.

(ie. 192.168.1[.]1 or 192.168.1(.)1 or 192.168.1[dot]1 or 192.168.1(dot)1 or 192 . 168 . 1 . 1)

Once the data is extracted I need to convert them all to valid format and remove duplicates.

My current code places the ip addresses into a string, which should be a dict? I know I need to use some kind of recursion to set the key value, but I feel there is a more efficient and modular way to complete the task.

```
import json, ordereddict, re

# define the pattern of valid and obfuscated ips
pattern = r"((([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))"

# open data file that contains ip addresses and other text
with open ("sample.txt", "r") as myfile:
    text=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

# put non normalized ip addresses in a dictionary
ips = {"data": [{"key1": match[0] for match in re.findall(pattern, text) }]}

# normalized ip addresses
for name, datalist in ips.iteritems():
    for datadict in datalist:
        for key, value in datadict.items():
            if value == "(dot)":
                datadict[key] = "."
            if value == "[dot]":
                datadict[key] = "."
            if value == " . ":
                datadict[key] = "."
            if value == " .":
                datadict[key] = "."
            if value == ". ":
                datadict[key] = "."

# write valid ip address to json file
with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(ips, outfile)
```

Sample data file

```
These are valid ip addresses 192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8
These are obfuscated 192.168.2[.]1 or 192.168.3(.)1 or 192.168.1[dot]1
192.168.1[dot]1 or 192.168.1(dot)1 or 192 .168 .1 .1 or 192. 168. 1. 1. or 192 . 168 . 1 . 1
This is what an invalid ip address looks like, they should be excluded 256.1.1.1 or 500.1.500.1 or 192.168.4.0
```

Expected result

```
192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, 192.168.3.1 , 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: just FYI `192.168.4.0` is a perfectly valid ip address.

Comment: Correct, I need only actual hosts, or 1-254

Comment: being pedantic 192.168.4.0 is valid host address :)